# Unable to display contents of a file in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to read the contents of a file named `pp.txt` and display it's contents on command line. My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

FILE *f;
float x;


f=fopen("pp.txt", "r");

if((f = fopen("pp.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Sorry! Can't read %s\n", "TEST1.txt");
}

else
{
printf("File opened successfully!\n");
}

fscanf(f, " %f", &x);

if (fscanf(f, " %f ", &x) != 1) {
fprintf(stderr, "File read failed\n");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

else
{
printf("The contents of file are: %f \n", x);
}


fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

After compiling I am getting `File opened successfully!File read failed`. My content of `pp.txt` is 34.5. Can anybody tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: you are reading it twice, and there is only 1 %f in it

Comment: Replace `if((f = fopen("pp.txt", "r")) == NULL)` with `if ( !f )`

Comment: Your idea of error checking is ridiculous!  Please think about it.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Sorry I don't understand why you are directing that comment to me.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry me too, thought that you write your comment to me ;)

Comment: @KarthikT I removed the statements `f=fopen("pp.txt", "r");` and `fscanf(f, " %f", &x);` but still getting the same error

Comment: @user227666 just in the off chance... did you compile it after removing it?

Comment: @KarthikT obviously! Surprisingly it's showing the same error message

Comment: @user227666 hint for future questions: do not use tabs when pasting code to SO, it messes up the indentation, which reduces chances of getting answer or upvotes, and increases risk of downvotes. Look at preview and fix formatting before posting the question.

Comment: @user227666 Also, when problem is solved, please mark the answer you think is best as accepted (click the tick mark).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that you are executing some of your functions twice.
here:

```
f=fopen("pp.txt", "r");

if((f = fopen("pp.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Sorry! Can't read %s\n", "TEST1.txt");
}
```

and here:

```
fscanf(f, " %f", &x);

if (fscanf(f, " %f ", &x) != 1) {
fprintf(stderr, "File read failed\n");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

change them to

```
f=fopen("pp.txt", "r");

if(f == NULL)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Sorry! Can't read %s\n", "TEST1.txt");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

and

```
r = fscanf(f, " %f", &x);

if (r != 1) 
{
  fclose(f); // If fscanf() fails the filepointer is still valid and needs to be closed
  fprintf(stderr, "File read failed\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

don't forget to define int r;

You are getting the error because your first `fscanf()` call reads the number and moves the filepointer beyond it. Now the second call doesn't find a number and fails.

Comment: *cough* `fclose()` *cough*

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `f=fopen("pp.txt","r");` before the first `if` statement and also remove `fscanf(f, " %f", &x);` before its corresponding `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file once

Read value once(unless you wanted to skip a float).

Close file before exiting.

Do NOT close file if it's NULL. -> will lead to undefined behavior

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

     FILE *f;
     float x;


     f = fopen("pp.txt", "r");

     if(f == NULL) // remove fopen here, already did that
     {
          fprintf(stderr, "Sorry! Can't read %s\n", "TEST1.txt");
     }
     else
     {
           printf("File opened successfully!\n");

           if (fscanf(f, " %f ", &x) != 1) // you were reading 2 times
           {    
                fprintf(stderr, "File read failed\n");
                fclose(f); // close the file before exiting
                return EXIT_FAILURE; 
           }
           else
           {
                printf("The contents of file are: %f \n", x);
           }

           fclose(f);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. Opening file twice. Resource leak.
2. You OS may have comma separator for floats instead of dot.
3. You didn't check result of first scanf

Proposal to topic starter: create algorythm (Flowchart) on paper before start coding. You will have a lot of simple mistakes, because you don't imagine, what your code is doing. You just try to make it working without understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your pattern `" %f "`, am guessing your file does not have these spaces.